# ERC20: exclude minting function

Tags: erc-20, mint, burn

Is it possible to write erc20 excluding main minting function but keeping initial mint (while deploying) and burn function? Any ideas to code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the ERC-20 token standard on ethereum.org: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/

Note that mint() and burn() are not listed as methods. This means that mint and burn are not required to be considered ERC-20.

What you are looking for is actually fairly common. I would recommend just going to https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/ and selecting burnable and including your desired "premint" amount. This should include all the functionality you have listed and you can simply copy and paste the code[image].